# case insensitive elasticsearch with uppercase or lowercase

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am working with elastic search and I am facing a problem. if any body gave me a hint , I will really thankful.

I want to analyze a field "name" or "description" which consist of different entries . e.g someone want to search Sara.  if he enter SARA, SAra or sara. he should be able to get Sara.
elastic search uses analyzer which makes everything lowercase.

I want to implement it case insensitive regardless of user input uppercase or lowercase name, he/she should get results.
I am using ngram filter to search names and lowercase which makes it case insensitive. But I want to make sure that a person get results if even he enters in uppercase or lowercase.

Is there any way to do this in elastic search?

```json
{"settings": {

        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 80
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "index_ngram": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [ "ngram_filter", "lowercase" ]
                },
```

I attach the example.js file which include json example and search.txt file to explain my problem . I hope my problem will be more clear now.
this is the link to onedrive where I kept both files.
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AsW4Pb3Y55Qjb34OtQI7qQotLzc

Answer (score 1):

The analysis process is executed for full-text search fields (analysed) twice: first when data are stored and the second time when you search. It’s worth to say that input JSON will be returned in the same shape as an output from a search query. The analysis process is only used to create tokens for an inverted index.  Key to your solution are the following steps:

1. Create two analysers one with ngram filter and second analyser
   without ngram filter because you don’t need to analyse input search
   query using ngram because you have an exact value that you want to search.
2. Define mappings correctly for your fields. There are two fields in
   the mapping that allow you to specify analysers. One is used for
   storage (analyzer) and second, is used for searching
   (search_analyzer) – if you specified only analyser field then
   specified analyser is used for index and search time.

You can read more about it here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html

And your code should look like that:

```
PUT /my_index
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "ngram_filter": {
               "type": "ngram",
               "min_gram": 1,
               "max_gram": 5
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "index_store_ngram": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "ngram_filter",
                  "lowercase"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
         "properties": {
            "name": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "index_store_ngram",
               "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

post /my_index/my_type/1
{
     "name": "Sara_11_01"
}

GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "name": "sara"
        }
    }
}

GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "name": "SARA"
        }
    }
}

GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "name": "SaRa"
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 1: updated code for a new example provided in the question

Comment: Adam when I put the above method in elasticsearch "head plugin". it always give the below mention error. Although tyoe is mention

Comment: "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "TokenFilter [analyzer] must have a type associated with it"

Comment: It's weird. I'm using Elasticsearch 2.3.2 and Sense chrome plugin and everything works correctly. What is your version of the Elasticsearch?

Comment: elastic search I am using has version "elasticsearch-2.4.1"...........   the above mention error I had solve but still it works either lowercase  or uppercase. . not both at the same time. .I implement exactly the above, but still its not working on both cases.

Comment: I added example.js and serach.txt file. is that enough?. .

Comment: In your json file, you have "Sara_11_01" value and you want to be able to search using only "Sara" word or you want to use an entire word "Sara_11_01"? Do you want to have a partial matching - allowing user to specify "Sa" to find this record?

Comment: if this is what you want then I updated code in my answer. I tested in on elasticsearch 2.4.1 as well.

Comment: I want to find entire word like SARA_11_01 ,  so when user enters SARA, SAra or sara he should able to get enitre Sara_11_01.  yes partial matching more suit to my project.

Comment: I am really thankful to you for your help in this regard.

Comment: My code does what you want to. Unless you want to search in this way: "Sara_11_01", "SARA_11_01", "SarA_11_01", "SA"  but then just change an analyzer from standard to keyword in index_store_ngram custom analyzer and that's all.

Comment: you mean to change tokenizer from standard to keyword in index_store_ngram custom analyzer?

Comment: analyzer.index_store_ngram.tokenizer ="keyword" and 
mappings.my_type.properties.name.search_analyzer ="keyword"

Comment: well I tried all these solutions but it couldn't solve my problem but I am thankful to you for your help and tips. Finally I explain a bit, maybe you could give me a tip. I am using head plugins in elasticsearch. e.g I set my_index and mapping setting by using "PUT" in head plugins and then I upload data through python script from sqlite database into elastic search and then I try to search by name and it still work on lowercase and when ever I enter uppercase SARA , it shows nothing. . am I making some mistake?  . .thanks alot again

Comment: I do not use "post" in head plugin to put all my data in elastic search. I used script to put my data from sqlite into elastic search. I guess I am missing something but don't know what.

Comment: Just a tip, test first using the easiest way - install chrome with sense :) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason you are using ngram? Elasticsearch uses the same analyzer on the "query" as well as the text you index - unless search_analyzer is explicitly specified,  as mentioned by @Adam in his answer. In your case it might be enough to use a [standard tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) with a lowercase filter

I created an index with the following settings and mapping:

```
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "custom_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "typehere": {
         "properties": {
            "name": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
            },
            "description": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Indexed two documents 
Doc 1

```
PUT /test_index/test_mapping/1
    {
        "name" : "Sara Connor",
        "Description" : "My real name is Sarah Connor."
    }
```

Doc 2

```
PUT /test_index/test_mapping/2
    {
        "name" : "John Connor",
        "Description" : "I might save humanity someday."
    }
```

Do a simple search

```
POST /test_index/_search?query=sara
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "name" : "SARA"
        }
    }
}
```

And get back only the first document. I tried with "sara" and "Sara" also, same results.

```
{
  "took": 12,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.19178301,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "test_mapping",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.19178301,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Sara Connor",
          "Description": "My real name is Sarah Connor."
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: with sara  its possible to search , but when its comes to Sara or SARA, then it shows nothing and that is the point where I am really struggling with uppercase.

Comment: I forget to mention that I am using "head plugin" with elastic search, so first I do mapping and then I upload data to elasticsearch and then I perform search.

Comment: @jay I thought about standard analyzer but zeeshankhan specified keyword analyzer... maybe he has a problem with keyword anaylzer because this analyzer put into the token everything what get in the input string. zeeshankhan give us an example json and search input string and tell what results you want to get. If you provide this I will create gist for you.

Comment: @jay I will provide an example today, then maybe my problem is more clear and some solution is there for it.  I am really thankful to all of you for helping me.

Comment: I added the example.js  and in search.txt I add my question of search input string mean the result I want from search.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in context of ElasticSearch `7.14`. So, let me re-format the ask of this question in another way:

`Irrespective of the actual case type provided in the match query, you would like to be able to get those documents that have been analysed with :`

```
   "tokenizer": "keyword",
   "filter": [ "ngram_filter", "lowercase" ]
```

Now, coming to the answer part:

It will not be possible to get the `match` query to return the docs that have been analysed with filter `lowercase` and the `match` query contains uppercase letters. The `analysis` that you have applied in the `settings` is applicable both while updating and searching data. Although, it is also possible to apply different analysers for updating and searching, I do not see that helping your case. You would have to convert the match query value to lowercase before making the query. So, if your filter is `lowercase`, you can not `match` by say `Sara` or `SARA` or `sAra` etc. The `match` param should be all lowercase, just as it is in your analyser.